# How to restart Strapi aaplication once it is being stopped

Tags: strapi

I install the Strapi application in my Mac and then I stopped the application, now I want to restart my same application and don't want to again install a new application. I had install strapi globally using this command `sudo npm i strapi@alpha -g`

Answer (score 1):

```
strapi develop
```

Or

```
npm run build
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm develop`. That should do once you are in the application folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below line:

```bash
npm run develop
```